# clojure core.async thread blocks

Tags: clojure, core.async

I have the following code:

```
(defn -db-producer-factory [order-ids-chan next-chan]
  (thread
    (prn "db starting...")
    (while true
      (do
        (prn "db starting2...")
        ;;
        ;; issue spot!
        ;; it stays blocked here-- the orderid doesnt come off the chan
        ;;
        (let [order-id (<!! order-ids-chan)]
          (prn "db->" order-id)
          (condp = order-id
            :finished (>!! next-chan :finished)
            :>> (supress-w-nextexc
                  (->>
                    ; get denorm'd order
                    (-> (r/-get-order :live order-id)
                        denorm/order->denormalized)
                    ; put in a map to avoid nils
                    (hash-map :data)
                    (>!! next-chan)))))))))

(defn -stats-producer-factory [stats-db-chan next-chan]
  (thread
    (while true
      (do
        (let [msg (<!! stats-db-chan)
              data (:data msg)]
          (when data
            (do
              (prn "stats-> " (-> data :order :order-id))
              (supress-w-nextexc
                (q/stats-order-insert (-> data :order)))
              (supress-w-nextexc
                (q/stats-item-insert (-> data :items)))))
          (>!! next-chan msg))))))

(defn -do-orderids [orderids]
  (let [finished-chan (chan)
        order-ids-chan (chan)
        stats-db-chan (chan)
        db-producer (-db-producer-factory order-ids-chan stats-db-chan)
        stats-producer (-stats-producer-factory stats-db-chan finished-chan)]

    (prn "pre-pub")
    ;; pub ids and finished message
    (map #(>!! order-ids-chan %) (conj orderids :finished))
    ;; wait for finish
    (prn "finished? " (<!! finished-chan))
    ;; allow time for finishing
    ;(Thread/sleep 3000)
    ;; close all chans
    (map close! [finished-chan order-ids-chan stats-db-chan db-producer stats-producer])
    ))
```

The process is initiated via a call to `-do-orderids` like `(-do-orderids [123])`.

The output of the execution is:

```
"db starting..."
"pre-pub"
"db starting2..."
```

But then it blocks. Why doesn't it pass the orderid at the "issue spot"?

Comment: I haven't reviewed the whole thing, but it could be due to using `(chan)` which creates a zero-length queue. This means a put will block until a simultaneous read occurs.  You may wish to make the queue non-zero length, perhaps `(chan 9)` for example. You could also use `put!` to have the put occur in a different thread (non-blocking).  Also, you may with to use a go-loop rather than `(while true ...)` in a separate thread

Comment: So far i've noticed that if i change `(map #(>!! order-ids-chan %) (conj orderids :finished))` to just `(>!! order-ids-chan 123)` it works... wondering why the map is part of the issue

Comment: Good catch.  Map is lazy and won't actually perform the calculation until the result is requested.  Try changing `map` to `mapv` (equiv to (vec (map ...))`

Comment: Why does `(->> (conj orderids :finished) (map #(>!! order-ids-chan %)))` also work? Does `->>` force the result out of laziness? Also, thanks for introducing me to `mapv`, very happy to stop doing `(doall (map))`. @AlanThompson

Comment: using `->>` should not make any difference, very surprised if you see a change from that alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program blocks because the `db-producer`, who’s blocked waiting for an order ID, never actually receives an order ID on `order-ids-chan`.

That is because `map` is lazy. So, in this invocation

```
(map #(>!! order-ids-chan %) (conj orderids :finished))
```

the mapping function is never called and no order ID is ever put onto the channel.

Clojure rule of thumb:

> **Never use `map` for side-effects!** Use [`run!`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/run!) instead.

I think substituting `run!` for `map` in that line (and on the last line where you call `close!` on the channel) should fix it.

Unrelated: all the `do` forms you used are redundant, you can safely remove them and reduce the level of nesting.